# Is there a general algorithm for Subset Selection with given constraints?

Tags: algorithm

Basically, a general algorithm to solve problems which resemble this puzzle:

A committee of five is to be selected from amongst 9 people A, B, C, D, E, P, Q, R, S.

- A and S have to be together.
- P cannot be put with R.
- D and Q cannot be together.
- C and E have to be together.
- R cannot be put with B.

Comment: "General algorithm"? This problem seems very specific.

Comment: All these conditions could be packed into one predicate of 9 boolean variables.  Then just solve it :-)  In this case the problem is easily brute-forced.

Comment: It's NP-hard by reduction from CLIQUE (use only "cannot be put with" constraints).

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I don't think so. If you construct a graph where `A cannot be put with B` implies `edge AB exists`, then the problem reduces to finding all the connected components of the graph. If there are 5 of them, then you can choose a committee which satisfies all the `cannot be put with` constraints. You can construct an instance of 2SAT with both types of constraints, but I don't if you can assert that it's satisfiable with exactly 5 (or n) boolean variables being true.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat That would be one way of constructing a graph. I'm saying that if you ignore all the `A must be with B` constraints, then this problem can be solved in linear time by constructing a graph of who can't be together, and choosing at most one node from each connected component. The 2SAT formulation isn't an instance of MAX-2SAT because all clauses in the formulation must still be true.

Comment: @Cookyt My comments about MAX-2SAT were misleading. The reduction to which I alluded above transforms the graph in which a clique is to be found by creating, for each missing edge, a constraint that its endpoints not serve together on the committee. It's easy to figure out if *some* committee can work. It's hard to figure out if there's a working committee of a particular size.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat You're right about this reducing to Clique. I made the false assumption that if `AB` is an edge in the "cannot be together" graph, and `BC` is an edge, then `AC` is an edge. I see now that if the algorithm I described above finds a committee, then it is definitely correct, but if it does not, it may be incorrect. Sorry for the hassle. That said, it may not matter to the OP if it's NP-complete as the brute-force solution may be good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is NP-hard by reduction from maximum independent set. The reduction sort of runs the other way, giving the following algorithm (exponential, but more sophisticated than brute force).

First assemble a graph of the "cannot be together" constraints, where each person is a vertex and each constraint is an edge. For every two people who must be together, identify them (i.e., put the edges together on one new vertex, deleting the two old vertices), keeping track of how many original vertices each new vertex represents. Delete all vertices with self-loops. Use [Bron--Kerbosch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm) to enumerate maximal independent sets (sets of vertices with no edge between any two set members), stopping when one over the size threshold is found. Return a subset of the appropriate size.